# How to include child processes in a webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, child-process

I have a Node app which uses the `fork` method to run a background process. The problem is that running the web pack configuration from the index doesn't bundle the background process's files resulting in an error when reaching the fork.

All the code uses Babel syntax along with some other goodies.

How do I tell webpack to also bundle the forked files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ If the code is in a source directory processed by your took chain should be fine. Without any details it's difficult to help.

Comment: The webpack configuration targets index.js file and creates a bundle. Inside the index.js there is a child process like fork('daemon.js'). Both files use babel syntax and other features enabled by webpack. When the bundle is run and gets to execute the daemon.js file, it crashes because it's using non-transpiled syntax. How do I include the child process file to the bundle and run it in a different process?

Comment: Can you fork a method? It's likely trying to run the file directly using the relative path hence getting a non-transpiled version.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the solution please?

Comment: webpack doesn't seem to pack files referenced with `child_process.fork()`

Comment: @AJ_1310 Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Seems like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fork-loader could do the trick here.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled into this problem myself, and thought I could mention that a quick fix is to add an additional entry in your webpack config for your child process (creates a separate bundle for your child process) and then make it use this bundle by some resolve-rules, or simply by [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader):

Some example webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
   // ...
   target: 'node',
   entry: {
     server: './server/server.js',
     daemon: './daemon.js'
   },
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../serverdist'),
     filename: '[name].bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       // ... your other existing rules for building the server code
       {
         test: /placeWhereYouAreCallingFork.js$/,
         loader: 'string-replace-loader',
         options: {
           search: 'daemon.js',
           replace: 'serverdist/daemon.bundle.js'
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   // Other webpack stuff...
};
```

This depends on the replace loader:

```
npm install --save-dev string-replace-loader
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution but it it worked for me, and I thougth it was quite simple.